# Delay with spawning Zombies?

Tags: java

I'm trying to spawn zombies with a second delay between each spawn but having no luck, There is no delay still even with my timer and it seems to be looping but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong???

Anyone could help would be appreciated <3

```
public class Zombie extends GameObject{

    Rectangle[] zombies = new Rectangle[60];

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public Zombie(float x, float y, ID id, SpriteSheet ss) {
        super(x, y, id, ss);

        Delay();
    }

    public void Delay(){
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);

    }

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){

            for(int i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++){

                Random rand = new Random();
                int result = rand.nextInt(6);

                if(result == 0){
                    x = 1000;
                    y = 200;
                }

                if(result == 1){
                    x = 100;
                    y = 200;
                }

                if(result == 2){
                    x = 100;
                    y = 600;
                }

                if(result == 3){
                    x = 1000;
                    y = 600;
                }

                if(result == 4){
                    x = 100;
                    y = 900;
                }

                if(result == 5){
                    x = 1000;
                    y = 900;
                }

                zombies[i] = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 48);

                if(i >= zombies.length){
                    task.cancel();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    public void tick() {

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        for(int i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect((int)zombies[i].x, (int)zombies[i].y, 32, 48);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 48);
    }
}
```

Comment: And render() needs to be called to.

Comment: Would i need to move my timer outside of this class?

Comment: What is that for loop in the task supposed to be doing?

Comment: i was trying to make it spawn a zombie every second from the array of 60 zombies

Comment: Why does a class called "Zombie" contain up to 60 zombies? That's confusing naming. If the class is supposed to represent a group then call it ZombieSwarm or ZombieGroup or something.

Comment: there is 60 zombies in the first round, then when it goes to round 2 there will be more zombies etc. but during the round i wanted to spawn them gradually every second hence the timer

Comment: @Luke - I could be reading your code wrong but I don't think you want that for loop in your task. I think you want all the stuff inside the for loop, just without the loop? 

It looks like to me that every second you loop through the zombies array and spawn a new zombie for each element in the array.

Comment: @ck1221 would you say move the timer outside of this class for when im calling them to be spawned??

Answer (score 0):

Check out the changes below. I haven't tested this, but I think it will work. I added the spawnedZombies counter and removed your for loop. I also changed the condition that stops the timer task.

I do agree with Michael's comment that this is confusing that you have 60 zombies inside the zombie class but that is another discussion :)

```
  Rectangle[] zombies = new Rectangle[60];

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        int spawnedZombies = 0;

        public Zombie(float x, float y, ID id, SpriteSheet ss) {
            super(x, y, id, ss);

            Delay();
        }

        public void Delay(){
            timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);

        }

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int result = rand.nextInt(6);

                if(result == 0){
                    x = 1000;
                    y = 200;
                }

                if(result == 1){
                    x = 100;
                    y = 200;
                }

                if(result == 2){
                    x = 100;
                    y = 600;
                }

                if(result == 3){
                    x = 1000;
                    y = 600;
                }

                if(result == 4){
                    x = 100;
                    y = 900;
                }

                if(result == 5){
                    x = 1000;
                    y = 900;
                }
        spawnedZombies++;
        zombies[spawnedZombies - 1] = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 48);


                if(spawnedZombies == zombies.length){
                    task.cancel();
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: There was a Exception in thread "thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ZombieSwarm.render(ZombieSwarm.java:82) which is the line g.fillRect((int)zombies[i].x, (int)zombies[i].y, 32, 48); in the render method @ck1221

Comment: I have changed the code around a bit and got it too work, however it doesn't spawn multiple zombies it spawns 1 then deletes it and spawns another @ck1221

Comment: Why is it deleting it? Is it spawning a new zombie every second but also deleting one every second?

Comment: Yes correct, one spawns but when the next one spawns after a second the previous one disappears, i believe this has something to do with the render method being looped elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know much about game dev or rendering. I won't be of much use with that. Is each zombie being drawn in a different location are do they keep spawning in the same spot?

Comment: its spawning the zombies perfectly the way i want in random spots however its just deleting the previous zombie when a new one spawns @ck1221

Comment: You may want to start a new question with information specific to the new issue. It could be caused by some logic in a class you haven't posted code for here? Like a game loop class or similar.